# Multiple selected rows to show multiple images in other view controller

Tags: ios, swift, cocoa-touch, uiviewcontroller

Choosing a string in a `UITableViewController`, shows pic of the same name in another view controller, which works as it should.

But the problem is when I want to choose multiple strings to show multiple different pics.
I've been trying to add another IBOutlet, doubling stuff, but it was just showing me the same pic twice.

Any idea?

multiple selection = true

**First VC segue:**

```
override func prepare(for segue: UIStoryboardSegue, sender: Any?) {

    if segue.identifier == "tablesegue" {

        if let indexPath = self.tableView.indexPathForSelectedRow {
            let selectedRow = indexPath.row
            let passingVal = segue.destination as! Tabulka_data
            passingVal.selectedImageName = self.tableItems[selectedRow]
        }
    }
}
```

**secondVC:**

```
@IBOutlet weak var pic: UIImageView!
var selectedImageName:String = ""

override func viewWillAppear(_ animated: Bool) {
    self.pic.image = UIImage(named: selectedImageName)
}
```

[two choices](https://i.stack.imgur.com/4032U.png)

Comment: You might want to use `indexPathsForSelectedRows` to get an Array of IndexPath, not only one. Then by using array (in both destination and rest) instead of single one, you might have what you want.

Comment: Seems like the right way to do it, but no idea how to write code. Any hint, please?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can try this

```
let yourDataArray = ["name 1","name 2","name 3","name 4","name 5"]
var imageSelected = [String]()

func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, numberOfRowsInSection section: Int) -> Int {
    return yourDataArray.count
}


func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> UITableViewCell {
    let cell = yourTable.dequeueReusableCell(withIdentifier: "cell", for: indexPath)
    cell.textLabel?.text = yourDataArray[indexPath.row]
    return cell
}


func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, didSelectRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) {
    imageSelected.append(yourDataArray[indexPath.row])
    print(imageSelected)
}

func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, didDeselectRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) {
    for (index, element) in imageSelected.enumerated() {
        if element == yourDataArray[indexPath.row] {
         imageSelected.remove(at: index)
        }
    }
    print(imageSelected)
}
```

You can use didSelectRowAt and didDeoRowAt to see which rows are selected, then just pass imageSelected to the second viewController

Comment: thanks, doing baby steps, I guess, I've already passed array to the other view controller, but how to unpack it there and make images with the same name? basically what I have is 
first VC:
passingVal.imagePassed = imageSelected
Second VC :
var imagePassed = [String]()

Comment: when you pass the data from the first VC to the second VC do you pass one string with image name right? in this case you pass a array of names so you can make this.


in secondVC add:
`var imageNamesRecevied = [String]()
var arrayImage = [UIImage]()

override func viewDidAppear(_ animated: Bool) {
        for image in imageNamesRecevied {
            let imageTemp = UIImage(named: image)
            arrayImage.append(imageTemp!)
        }
    }
`
to create a array of images in secondVC